# Passing data between themes and the page settings

Tags: php, design-patterns

I'm designing a small CMS with best practices I learned. I came to this conclusion when comes to including page content and themes to each page depending by user or whatever.

But how could I make this better? I can change title of included modules this way, but I cannot modify titles if the included modules have another included sub modules.

My main question would be how should I rather handle the themes. But I would also like some criticism about the actual CMS design. Any flaws, security issues or anything that could be much better.

Index page from where I include all 'modules':

```
<?php
    error_reporting(-1);
    define('CMS_TOKEN', '');
    include('config/config.inc.php');
    $cms = new cms();
    if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') && !empty($_GET['page'])) {
        $cms->IncludeModule($_GET['page']);
    }
    else {
        foreach($cms->GetModuleList() as $module) {
            $cms->ConcatContent('<a href="index.php?page='.$module.'">'.$module.'</a><br />');
        }
    }
    include($cms->GetTheme() . "/head.php");
    echo $cms->GetContent();
    include($cms->GetTheme() . "/foot.php");
?>
```

Example module.

```
<?php
    $module_name        = 'User Panel';
    $module_directory   = 'user';
    $this->SetPageName($module_name); 
    if(!defined('CMS_TOKEN')) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else {
        if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['username'] != 'anonymous') {
            $this->ConcatContent("<h2>$module_name</h2>");
            if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {
                $edit = $_GET['edit'];
                foreach($this->GetCustomModuleList($module_directory) as $module) {
                    $this->ConcatContent("<a href=\"index.php?page=user&edit=$module\"> $module </a> | ");
                } 
                $this->ConcatContent("<br /><br />"); 
                if(in_array($module, $this->GetCustomModuleList('user'))) {
                    include($this->GetModuleDirectory() . '/' . $module_directory . '/' . $edit . $this->GetModuleExtention());
                }
                else {
                    $this->ConcatContent("Selected module doesn't exist!");
                }
            }
            else {
                foreach($this->GetCustomModuleList($module_directory) as $module) {
                    $this->ConcatContent("<a href=\"index.php?page=user&edit=$module\">$module</a> | ");
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            header('Location: index.php?page=login');
        }
    }
?>
```

Some core CMS code:

```
<?php
    class cms {     
        // lots of variables
        // custom modules config variables - will always change
        private $config_custom_module_list;
        private $config_custom_module_directory;
        function __construct() { /* ... */ }
        // lots of getter/setters       
        public function GetModuleList() {
            $moduleList = array();
            foreach($this->config_module_list as $module) {
                if($this->CheckModule($module) == 1) { // 1 for pure module result
                    $moduleNoExt = str_replace($this->GetModuleExtention(), '', $module);
                    $moduleList[] = str_replace($this->GetModuleExtention(), '', $moduleNoExt);
                }
            }
            return $moduleList;
        }
        private function SetModuleList() {
            $this->config_module_list = array_diff(scandir($this->GetModuleDirectory(), 1), array('..', '.'));
        }   
        private function SetCustomModuleList($owner) {
            if($this->CheckCustomModuleDirectory($owner)) {
                $this->config_custom_module_list = array_diff(scandir($this->GetModuleDirectory() . '/' . $owner, 1), array('..', '.'));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        private function CheckModule($module) {
            $moduleNameArray = explode(".", $module);
            $countParts = count($moduleNameArray);
            if($countParts == 1) {
                return 2;
            }
            else if($countParts == 3) {
                $moduleNameExtention = '.' .  $moduleNameArray[1] . '.' . $moduleNameArray[2];
                if($this->GetModuleExtention() == $moduleNameExtention) {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }       
        public function IncludeModule($name) {
            if(in_array($name, $this->GetModuleList())) {   
                include($this->GetModuleDirectory() . '/' . $name . $this->GetModuleExtention());
            }
            else {
                echo 'Module Doesn\'t Exist! Critical Error!';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found easy solution. Just control the title from the end of the script like this:

```
<?php
    $module_name        = 'User Panel';
    $module_directory   = 'user';

    if(!defined('CMS_TOKEN')) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else {
        if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']['username'] != 'anonymous') {
            $this->ConcatContent("<h2>$module_name</h2>");
            if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {
                $edit = $_GET['edit'];
                foreach($this->GetCustomModuleList($module_directory) as $module) {
                    $this->ConcatContent("<a href=\"index.php?page=user&edit=$module\"> $module </a> | ");
                } 
                $this->ConcatContent("<br /><br />"); 

                $module_name = 'SOME TITLE'; // ---- here

                if(in_array($module, $this->GetCustomModuleList('user'))) {
                    include($this->GetModuleDirectory() . '/' . $module_directory . '/' . $edit . $this->GetModuleExtention());
                }
                else {
                    $this->ConcatContent("Selected module doesn't exist!");
                }
            }
            else {
                foreach($this->GetCustomModuleList($module_directory) as $module) {
                    $this->ConcatContent("<a href=\"index.php?page=user&edit=$module\">$module</a> | ");
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            header('Location: index.php?page=login');
        }
    }
    $this->SetPageName($module_name); 
?>
```